# How to send to pulses to a CMOS Counter

Tags: cmos, counter

I have tried to find answers to this many times, and the only solution I have been able to find is having two 555 Timers (or a 556) one in astable, and one in monostable.

I could easily do this with an arduino or something, but thought using CMOS and logic IC would be more fun and challenging.

But in short I have a project which will be using two 4029 counters to keep track of scores (and a few other features, but irrelevant to this question), and I have three buttons, one to increase the counter by one, another button to increase by two, and another to increase by three.

I am having trouble finding a simple circuit that can pulse the 4029 two or three times, I know I could just press the one button two or three times, but with how this will be used separate buttons are preferred.

Not sure what other information I can supply that might help explain better.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I have used CD4013 as you are using 4029.

R1C1 sets the monostable LOW time. As long as this is longer than the switch bounce time, it will debounce the switches.

The rising end of each pulse, triggers the next stage

There will only be a small high pause between pulses - optional C2 will lengthen it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY0dew.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks heaps, that seems much simpler than my other ideas!